# Listen to audio of a virtual machine in the background?

Tags: windows, audio, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I know it's a weird question but the scenario is that I am a Windows user and I made a script which reports "something" with a sound in a Debian virtual machine, but when I have it minimized I can not hear the sound.

I wonder if there is a way to listen to the audio of a virtual machine while it's in the background?

Comment: Which virtualization software are you using to host the VM?

Comment: Hi, I use Oracle VM virtual box

Comment: can i ask why you need to report with a sound?
wouldn't it be easier to send some kind of message to a monitoring proccess elsewhere?

Comment: I don't know how to that, btw the script just reports me once my laptop's battery reach 100% so i can disconect it and prevent overcharging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot test it on Windows because I'm using Linux but I found this [feature request](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=12237) in which the opener would like to **have** the feature that the sound gets minimized when window has been minimized. This makes me assume that your problem happens because of a Windows settings (somewhere) and not a VirtualBox setting as VirtualBox seems not to have that "feature".

An alternative might be to use `Seamless Mode`. This integrates windows (and alert boxes) from the guest OS into the current Windows desktop session. This way you should be able to hear the sound.

To achieve this, select "View" in the menu bar of the VM window and then "Switch to seamless mode"

Comment: Nice to hear that it works :)